# PBS keeps aborting my jobs

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, hpc, pbs, numa

I am requesting 14 processors from one one (each has 32) like this:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=14

#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00
```

And with lower `ppn` it almost always works, but once I get to numbers higher than 14-ish, the job begins execution and terminates immediately. `tracejob` is singularly unhelpful:

```
tracejob 14753.hpc2

Job: 14753.hpc2

01/21/2017 11:12:36  L    Considering job to run
01/21/2017 11:12:36  L    Job run
01/21/2017 11:12:36  M    Resource_List.place = scatter
01/21/2017 11:12:36  M    make_cpuset, vnode hpc2[0]:  hv_ncpus (2) > mvi_acpus (0) (you are not expected to understand this)
01/21/2017 11:12:36  M    start_exec, new_cpuset failed
01/21/2017 11:12:36  M    kill_job
01/21/2017 11:12:36  M    hpc2 cput= 0:00:00 mem=0kb
01/21/2017 11:12:37  M    Obit sent
01/21/2017 11:12:37  M    copy file request received
01/21/2017 11:12:37  M    staged 2 items out over 0:00:00
01/21/2017 11:12:37  M    delete job request received
01/21/2017 11:12:37  M    delete job request received
01/21/2017 11:12:38  M    no active tasks
01/21/2017 11:12:38  M    delete job request received
```

I have at times successfully requested more cpus, so it's not completely deterministic. Is there a way to debug this?

As a side node, any job that requests more than one node sits in the queue forever and is never started, I don't know if that is related.

Comment: What resource manager and version are you using? Same question for the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a "qrun" and forcefully trying to start this job on the specified vnode?

As a possible solution try restarting your MOM (Machine Oriented Mini-server) or set the sharing as exclusive on the MOM (of course you need to be a privileged user to do that).